# socket read()'s byte offset (linux)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

When we use `read()` function with file descriptor(not socket), it has byte-offset like this.

1. `read(file descriptor, message1, 20);`
2. `read(file descriptor, message2, 40);`

After number1 command, the file descriptor's byte offset is 20 as it says.
Then, number 2 command read the file at the byte offset 20, and the file descriptor's final offset is 60 now.

So, now my question is about socket. Let me explain you situations.

On server-client model, client sends server 100 bytes(lets assum it's string data). But, unfortunately, server receive data sequentially 10, 20, 70(not 100 bytes at once.)

So, because of this situation, server source code is like this.

```
 51         while(recv_len<100)
 52         {
 53                 recv_count=read(cli_sock, message[recv_len], 1024);
 54         
 55                 if(recv_count==-1)
 56                         error_handling("read() error");
 57 
 58                 recv_len+=recv_count;
 59         }
```

So client writes 10 bytes data one of 100 bytes string to server, at first.

Anyway, server execute `read()` function, and reads 1024 bytes. So, the server takes 10 bytes. But, its byte-offset is 1024 now.

So, after client's second data(20 bytes data), server must read at byte offset 1024. Then, how can server reads 20 bytes which is sent from client? I mean originally, server must read 20 bytes at byte offset 10(not 1024), because 10 bytes data had sent before 20bytes. But, server is at byte offset 1024. How this can be possible?

Comment: Why do you think that is an offset? It is the number of bytes you want to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it wrong. The third parameter of a read() call isn't an offset, it represents the number of bytes you want to read, at max.
The actual number read is returned by the read() call.

Look here : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

---

Also, you should pass a pointer to read() calls.

So `message[recv_len]` isn't gonna do. You're looking for `message + recv_len`

Answer (score 3):

This

```
recv_count=read(cli_sock, message[recv_len], 1024);
```

will not do what you think.

It should be :

```
recv_count=read(cli_sock, message + recv_len, 1024 - recv_len);
```

or

```
recv_count=read(cli_sock, &message[recv_len], 1024 - recv_len);
```

read the man page and if don't understand something, don't hesitate to ask for precision (even thought that blue112 already explain it all).

Comment: Yes.  I prefer the second version - it makes the pointer arithmetic less obvious:)